#  Array of structure Layout in Memory 

Tags: c, memory

```
 int a[2];
```

This in memory actually looks like:

```
 //Assuming int is 2 bytes 

 add=2000, a[0]=124    

 add=2002, a[1]=534
```

How does this actually look like in memory

```
 struct l {

 struct l    * n;

 long int pad[7];

 };          

 struct l container;
```

I am unable to visualize. Please help!

BTW this is taken from section 3.3.2 of [What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory](http://lwn.net/Articles/252125/)

Comment: That's a type, not a variable; it won't be in memory.

Comment: *"//Assuming int is 2 bytes"* Not a great assumption these days, but ok.  Also, that is not how the array would look in memory.  It has been allocated as an array with two elements, yet you show three.

Comment: @EdS. My understanding was: what I see (and even what I dont see) on screen is stored in 'some' memory... so when I write this type, why no memory will be allocated?

Comment: No memory is allocated until you instantiate a variable of that type. The type definition really has meaning only to the compiler.

Comment: @EdS. Sorry, I missed that line...updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a pointer in your architecture is 4 bytes and a long int in your architecture is 4 bytes:

```
struct l {
   struct l    * n;
   long int pad[7];
};

struct l someName;
```

layout will look like:

```
add=2000, someName.n
add=2004, someName.pad[0]
add=2008, someName.pad[1]
...
add=2028, someName.pad[6]
```

Answer (score 4):

The layout of `struct l` would be as follows. As the book says it will occupy 32 bytes.

```
   addr   ref
   -----------------
   2000:  n
   2004:  pad[0]
   2008:  pad[1]
     ...
   2028:  pad[6]
```

On a 32-bit system `struct l*`, a pointer to a structure would occupy 4 bytes. A variable of type `long int` would occupy the same amount of memory.

Comment: +1, but you forgot to mention that you're following the assumption that a `long int` is 4 bytes, as well as the pointer :)

Comment: @EitanT Thank you. This assumption is also taken in the Ulrich Drepper's paper.

Comment: The OP said he assumes `int` is 16-bit so the system is likely a  8 or 16-bit system but not a 32-bit system.

Answer (score 1):

this just means every time you allocate memory for struct l, you will need 4 byte (pointer) + 4 byte (let's say long int is 4 byte) * 7.

so using your system, it should be:
    add=2000 *n
    add=2004 pad[0]
    add=2008 pad[1] 
    ...